# Ring Theory and Modules in Norm

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R = Z[\sqrt{5}]$ and $f : R → Z$ be defined as $f(x + y\sqrt{5}) := | x^2 − 5y^2|$. Then prove that
$f$ is multiplicative : $f(αβ) = f(α)f(β)$, $∀α, β ∈ R$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please add some of your own thoughts on how to solve the problem, so we can see where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Call $\alpha = a+ b \sqrt{5}$, and $\beta = c+ d \sqrt{5}$. Then $\alpha \beta = (ac+5bd) + (ad+bc) \sqrt{5}$. So you have simply to verify that

$$|a^2-5b^2|\cdot |c^2-5d^2| = |(ac+5bd)^2 -5 (ad+bc)^2|$$